# How to select the outer edges of a plane in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

I have made this shape in geometry nodes. How would I go about making a selection of just the outer edges excluding all the other edges within the shape?

Comment: Do those cells have faces?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming those cells are filled with faces, there's an easy-to-utilize difference between the outer edges and the inner ones: outer edges belong only to one face, while inside edges are always part of at least two. We can make a selection based on that distinction with the help of the `Edge Neighbors`—*Face Count* socket:

[image]