# Selecting outmost edges with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, select

I want to select all outmost edges/vertices of an object with geometry nodes (marked in included image).

I thought it was going to be fairly straightforward but I am really struggling with this one. Does anyone have a method for this?

[image]

Comment: Does this help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/284474/how-to-select-the-outer-edges-of-a-plane-in-geometry-nodes

Comment: I think it does! Thank you! :)